# How do I delete an immutable encrypted file?

Tags: ext4, disk-encryption, xattr

I was experimenting with encryption on an ext4 filesystem and I encrypted a file (using `fscrypt`) which was set to be immutable (via `chattr +i`). I have now lost the encryption key and uninstalled `fscrypt`.

I would like to delete the file, but when I try to delete it, I get the following error:

```
# rm foo
rm: cannot remove 'foo': Operation not permitted
```

and when I try to make it mutable:

```
# chattr -i foo
chattr: Required key not available while reading flags on foo
```

Therefore, I believe I cannot delete the file as it is immutable and I cannot change its attributes due to encryption. Any suggestions?

---

### Edit:

I have tried the following and they do not work:

1. Deleting/modifying the files from a Live USB. The same errors occur.
2. Trying after removing the `encrypt` feature, as Ángel suggested. `fsck` also doesn't throw any errors for some reason.

Output of `findmnt` (`testdir` contains `foo`) and filesystem properties:

```
$ findmnt --target testdir
TARGET SOURCE    FSTYPE OPTIONS
/      /dev/sda4 ext4   rw,relatime

# tune2fs -l /dev/sda4 | grep "Filesystem features"
Filesystem features:      has_journal ext_attr resize_inode dir_index filetype needs_recovery extent 64bit flex_bg sparse_super large_file huge_file dir_nlink extra_isize metadata_csum
```

Comment: Encryption should not matter. Removing a file does not look inside the file. However I don't know what the problem is. You need the appropriate capability (so run as root, with sudo), but that does not account for the error message.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor: my understanding is that `fscrypt` works on a directory level (also, it's a FS feature, so it will persist even after uninstalling the tools), so I'm almost as suprised the OP can `cd` into the directory and still see a meaningful filename.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor I tried running both commands as root. It makes no difference.

Comment: please update question to show: output of `findmnt --target directory-that-contains-foo`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the filesystem unmounted, you should be able to use `debugfs -w -R "rm path_to_file" /dev/sda1` to delete the file.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way would be to format a new ext4 partition there and start fresh. However, I understand that may not be convenient for you.

Assuming the partition is on /dev/sda1, I would try doing -while the filesystem is not mounted-:

```
debugfs -w -R "feature -encrypt" /dev/sda1
fsck.ext4 /dev/sda1
```

The debugfs command will remove the encrypt feature from the ext4 filesystem, and the following fsck should detect all encrypted directories as errors, and would hopefully offer to remove them. Even if they are not removed, I expect the encryption flag to be gone (and the contents to be garbage), so you should then be able to make un-inmmutable and remove the normal way.

Comment: Note that after e2fsck is run, you still need to remove the `immutable` flag from the file and unlink it.

Comment: That's what I meant with `you should then be able to make un-inmmutable and remove the normal way`, yes.